# Script to edit a MySQL table using data already in the table?

Tags: mysql

I've made a table in MySQL that contains user details. 2 of the fields in this database are firstname and lastname. How do I go about implementing a script that goes down every row in this table and populates the 'login' column with the format 'firstname.lastname'? This is a small/simple dataset, so we can assume no duplicate names. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `USERS` SET `login`= CONCAT(`firstname`, '.', `lastname`);
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy. Thank you so much!